# how to fix overlay background height according to fancybox content height (large overlay or a scrolling page.)

Tags: jquery, html, css, fancybox, fancybox-2

please any one tell me how to fix overlay background height(overlayOpacity portion) according to fancybox content height(means no extra spaces to top and bottom of the fancybox) and i'm using fancybox 2(latest version)

code:

```
jQuery.fancybox({                           
   'scrolling': 'no',
   'hideOnContentClick': true,
   'autoSize'    : true,
   'fitToView'  : false,
   'height' : '100%',
   'hideOnOverlayClick' : true,
   'content' : jQuery('.EngpopupContent'),
   'overlayShow' : true,
   'overlayOpacity' : 0.9,
   'overlayColor' : '#000',
   'transitionIn' : 'elastic',
   'transitionOut' : 'elastic',
   'changeFade' : 'fast',
   'easingIn' : 'swing',
   'easingOut' : 'swing',
   'showCloseButton' : true,
   //'showNavArrows' : true,
   'enableEscapeButton' : true,
   'onStart': function(){
       jQuery("#fancybox-overlay").css({"position":"fixed"});
   }
});
```

reference [link](http://www.carid.com/ace-wheels/concept-5-silver-480984.html)

i need to be working fancybox exact like above reference url... Please click on "Please Select Product options" button

Please help me anyone...

Comment: in the link of reference, the height IS NOT 100% (it may look like but is not), it's a fixed height almost as long as the view port but if you reduce the viewport size you will need to scroll down to see the content. Additionally options in fancybox v2.x are not compatible with v1.3.x (you are using options for both versions)

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly you need to remove the margin and padding from the rendered content.
you can do this by adding two more options to your config

```
jQuery.fancybox({ 
//other options
'padding': 0,
'margin' : 0,
//other options
```

For more info visit http://fancybox.net/api

Later edit:

Now i think i understood. If you are using the default layout with close button try adding this to your CSS file :

```
#fancybox-outer { background: transparent;}
#fancybox-close {top: 25px !important;}
#fancybox-wrap {top: -45px  !important;}
```

This will remove the white background from the top and position wrapper closer to the top (you will need to set the padding and margin to 0 if you don't want to see the white side border)

Comment: no it's not working
i'm talking about opacity background instead of inner fancybox background
and your given code work for (Space between FancyBox wrapper and content)

Comment: the default settings are the same for 2.x and 1.x except the new features added in 2.x of course. I linked to the v1.x because it displays the default values

Comment: @AndreiR wrong: settings for v1.3.x are not compatible (and don't exist actually) with fancybox v2.x. and vice versa.